# Qual a diferença entre "reference path" e "import" no TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

```
/// <reference path="arquivo.ts" />
```

---

```
import "./arquivo.ts";
```

---

Qual a diferença e quando usar cada um no Node.js com TypeScript?

É necessário ser um arquivo `ts` ou posso importar diretamente um `js`?

Ter uma `class` é necessário ou posso importar um arquivo contendo só funções?

Answer (score 2):

> Qual a diferença...

A primeira sintaxe `/// <reference path="arquivo.ts" />` é usada em arquivos de tipagem (`*.d.ts`) para **referenciar outros arquivos de tipagem**. Isso é útil para compartilhar tipos entre arquivos sem precisar exportá-los.

A segunda sintaxe `import "./arquivo.ts";` é usada para **importar módulos** em arquivos `.ts` e `.js` no Node.js. Isso permite que você compartilhe código entre arquivos e projetos.

> É necessário ser um arquivo `ts` ou posso importar diretamente um `js`?

Essa sintaxe é específica do Typescript e **não é suportada pelo JavaScript puro**. Para quem não sabe, o nome disso é [Triple-Slash Directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html), são válidas apenas no começo dos arquivos e são usadas para instruir o compilador do TypeScript a incluir arquivos adicionais no processo de [transpilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189894/o-que-%C3%A9-transpila%C3%A7%C3%A3o) para código JavaScript.

> Ter uma `class` é necessário ou posso importar um arquivo contendo só funções?

Não é necessário ter uma classe em um arquivo para importá-lo. Você pode importar arquivos contendo apenas funções, variáveis e/ou constantes.