# O que é Transpilação?

Tags: terminologia, ecmascript-6

Eu comecei a ler um [artigo](https://booker.codes/how-to-build-and-publish-es6-npm-modules-today-with-babel/) sobre EcmaScript 6 e me deparei com o termo *Transpilation*, que em português seria *Transpilação*. Além desse, percebi que outros artigos usam esse termo.

É a primeira vez na minha vida de programação que me deparo com esse  termo.

O que isso significa? Esse *trans* tem a ver com traduzir código ou algo do tipo?

Comment: *Não, não estou falando de nada referente a desodorantes*

Comment: Ainda bem que você alertou Wallace!

Comment: E sobre _desodolante_?

Comment: recomendo a leitura: https://blog.codecasts.com.br/ecossistema-javascript-parte-04-transpilers-734f77422316

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[Pensei que já sabia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102787/101) :P

De fato a transpilação é uma tradução, no fundo a transpilação é uma especialização da compilação. Todo o processo é feito igualzinho o que o compilador faz, a diferença é apenas que no compilador tradicional o alvo é um código de mais baixo nível, provavelmente alguma forma de Assembly ou código de máquina, enquanto que o transpilador tem como alvo um código fonte de uma linguagem de alto nível diferente ou a mesma escrita de outra forma.

É usado pelo [CoffeeScript, TypeScript e o próprio JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101) para compatibilizar versões, só para citar os casos mais óbvios do JavaScript. Tem muita linguagem que gera um fonte em C em vez de gerar um código de baixo nível.

Então você pode programar no ES6 sem medo porque mesmo que queira suportar navegadores antigos que ainda estão em versão mais antiga da especificação EcmaScript basta fazer a transpilação do ES6 para uma versão mais antiga e poder rodar em todo lugar. Isto é bem fácil já que as novidades do JS são quase  todas praticamente *syntax sugar*. Outros exemplos são [Flow](https://flow.org/) e [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Pode ser vantajoso por disponibilizar essa linguagem em diversas plataformas e obter otimizações que essa linguagem faz. Também pode ter algumas desvantagens como mais dificuldade para depuração precisando fazer um mapeamento, pode haver impedância do modelo de memória entre a linguagem fonte e a usada como alvo, entre outras.

Um [exemplo do TS fazendo a transpilação](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20module%20Modulo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20export%20class%20ClassePublica%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20classePrivada%20%3A%20ClassPrivada%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.classePrivada%20%3D%20new%20ClassPrivada()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20teste()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.classePrivada.teste()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20class%20ClassPrivada%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20teste()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%27it%20works%27)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Fazendo um adendo em relação ao ES6 para versões anteriores existem vários sites fazendo a  "`conversão`" (termo mais fajuto) / `transpilação` como por exemplo o https://babeljs.io/

Answer (score 31):

Transpilar é uma mistura de compilar e traduzir. Por outras palavras é uma ferramenta para gerar uma nova versão de um dado codigo.

Nos ultimos anos em JavaScript a linguagem avançou muito. Como os browsers andam mais devagar e não conseguem acompanhar o ritmo começaram a surgir soluções para os desenvolvedores poderem usar as novas tecnologias no código que escrevem, e depois na hora de usar esse código ele ser transpilado para uma versão de JavaScript que os browsers aceitem. A Babel é o exemplo melhor disso, e um exemplo prático seria:

```
var optionsA = {um: 1};
var optionsB = {...optionsA, dois: 2};
console.log(optionsB);
```

que usa tecnologias futuras, já aprovadas ou em fase de aprovação e transpilado fica:

```
"use strict";

var _extends = Object.assign || function (target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i]; for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } } return target; };

var optionsA = { um: 1 };
var optionsB = _extends({}, optionsA, { dois: 2 });
console.log(optionsB);
```

Assim compatível com ECMAScript 5.

Se juntarmos a isto o conceito de [AST](http://Abstract_syntax_tree), que permite analisar o código e os seus componentes, então podemos transpilar não só para versões diferentes de JavaScript mas para outras linguages, primas ou não.

Answer (score 12):

Seria uma conversão de uma linguagem para outra.

Quando, por exemplo, você programa em TypeScript, é necessário um transpiler para convertê-lo em Javascript.

Quando você vai usar o React e escreve em Jsx, é necessário um *transpiler* para converter o código em Vanilla Javascript, ou com CoffeeScript, por exemplo. Ou quando usa LESS ou SASS, por exemplo, um *transpiler* o transforma em CSS.

Inclusive, existem *transpilers* que te permitem escrever a linguagem Javascript com recursos ainda não compatíveis com todos os navegadores (recursos ainda em teste, recursos "do futuro", como classes, herança, spread operator, rest parameters, async away, etc.) e convertem seu código para uma versão mais legada, tornando-o disponível para todos os navegadores atuais.

Answer (score -3):

De maneira geral, a função de um transpiler é traduzir um código escrito em linguagem para um código de outra.