# Diferenças entre um transpilador e um compilador

Tags: terminologia, independente-de-linguagem, compiladores

Ultimamente se tem ouvido falar muito do termo transpilador (*transpiler*). Porém, não me parece clara a diferença de um *transpiler* (Babel, por exemplo) para um compilador (*compiler*) tradicional. Os dois traduzem código de uma linguagem para outra, não?

Quais as reais diferenças entre um compilador e um transpilador?

Comment: Nossa, é duplicada, e o pessoal sai tacando respostas, sem pesquisar :\

Comment: Pesquisa ai e coloca para gente ver... @WallaceMaxters

Comment: A outra duplicada: [O que é Transpilação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189894/18246)

Comment: Pronto agora, marca como duplicada...@WallaceMaxters

Comment: Algo que pego no pé e o pessoal não entende, não é só o AP quem deve dar uma breve pesquisada pra ver se não é dup, quem vai responder pode muito bem fazer isto, afinal de conta somos uma comunidade, não custa nada ser **um pouquinho altruísta** e colaborar apontando respostas existentes, eu já peguei fama de chato de tanto que falo disso, mas o pessoal fica afobado pra responder. Uma pena mesmo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu acho que é desnecessário, colocar isso da forma como o "Valace" colocou,  como se responder uma duplicada fosse passível de negativo... Quer dizer, não está sendo levada em consideração a boa vontade de quem tá respondendo.Aliás qualquer tipo de comentário, uma vez que o sistema nos oferece a ferramenta de marcar como duplicada.  E me diga uma coisa, onde tá dizendo que antes de responder o AR tem de pesquisar para ver se não há duplicadas(não estou dizendo que é uma boa prática, apenas que responder não é uma má prática ao meu ver)?

Comment: @MagicHat fica tranquilo :) . Não estou dizendo que é regra, estou falando de sobre colaborar melhor com a comunidade, nada é perfeito, mas não custa nada dar uma ajudinha

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pow mais ajuda do que tentar responder... Quando eu vejo possivel dup, ou alguma direção apontando para uma resposta eu considero, mas até as respostas saírem num tinha nada... E daí vem alguém criticando, colocando de forma que tá errado responder, ai eu pego mal. Mas tô tranquilex.... Agora não existe nem no meta ou na central de ajuda, algo que fala sobre isso?

Comment: @MagicHat não é questão de regra ou debates, é só mesmo uma sugestão de como fazer uso da ferramenta, no caso botão `Fechar` > `Duplicada de ...`. Mas é algo que meio que já desisti de levar adiante, tem realmente problemas bem maiores no site, mas que de fato não serão resolvidos também :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento faz parte, preciso pegar o hábito de dar uma pesquisada antes, inconscientemente parto do pressuposto que ao digitar a pergunta o sistema já oferece algo ao AP, então se chega na lista de recentes seria pq não há dup, mas sabemos que não é assim que funfa...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De maneira clara e objetiva:

- Compilador: recebe código-fonte em linguagem de alto/médio nível (mais próximo dos humanos) como entrada e, como saída, produz código em linguagem de baixo nível (mais próximo da máquina). Ex.: C -> código objeto, Java -> JVM bytecode.
- Transpilador: recebe código-fonte em linguagem de alto/médio nível como entrada e, como saída, produz código em outra linguagem de alto/médio nível. Ex.: Typescript -> Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

A grosso modo o *transpiler* é um tipo de compilador que traduz um código escrito em uma linguagem médio/alto nível para um código de uma outra linguagem de médio/alto nível.

Já o compilador traduz da linguagem médio/alto nível para uma linguagem de nível mais baixo, uma linguagem de montagem, por exemplo.

[Fonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler)