# Como usar o Emscripten?

Tags: javascript, html, c++

Queria converter meus códigos em C++ para JavaScript para poder usá-los em paginas Web. Como posso fazer isso? Pelo que pesquisei o Emscripten faz isso, só que não sei como utilizá-lo.

Como funciona?

Como utilizá-lo?

Quais seus recursos?

Como integrar o JavaScript gerado no HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pergunta é um pouco ampla, vou responder o que dá.

> Queria converter meus códigos em C++ para JavaScript para poder usa-los em paginas Web.

Não é tão simples assim. Embora seja possível fazer isso, se o código não foi preparado para trabalhar no *browser, ou pelo menos seja uma biblioteca que seja integrada em um código preparado para isto, nem perca tempo.

> Como posso fazer isso ? Pelo que pesquisei o Emscripten faz isso, só que não sei como utilizá-lo.

Dizer como fazer é muito amplo, seria um manual. Sugiro estudar um pouco de [WebAssembly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199158/101), que elimina a necessidade do Emscripten e resolve de uma forma muito melhor.

> Como funciona ?

Ele é um compilador (ou [transpilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189894/101) então é parecido com [o que ocorre com TypeScript ou CoffeScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101)), onde ele pega o código em C ou C++ e gera um código JavaScript que roda no navegador. É usado um *script* chamado [asm.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asm.js) para executar o código gerado. A performance é bem ruim, ao contrário do WebAssembly que é usado até para melhorar a performance do JS.

> Como utilizá-lo?

Com um problema mais específico talvez dê para responder em outra pergunta. Mas não sei se ainda deseja aprender algo obsoleto.

> Quais seus recursos?

Não sei o que quer dizer.

> Como integrar o JavaScript gerado no HTML?

Muito amplo para responder aqui.

Comment: emscripten está obsoleto ?

Comment: Essencialmente sim :)