# Por que o TypeScript quando é compilado, converte "let" para "var" nas variáveis?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, declaração-de-variável

Se `let variavel = "valor";` também é compatível em `JavaScript`, porque na compilação do TypeScript, ele transforma para `var variavel = "valor"`?

[Faça o teste aqui mesmo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/):

```
function foo(){
  var x = 1;
  let y = 3;
  if (true){
    var x = 2;
    let y = 4;
    console.log(x); //Irá resultar 2.
    console.log(y); //Irá resultar 4.
  }
  console.log(x); //Irá resultar 2 porque o escopo do 'var' abrangiu toda a função foo().
  console.log(y); //Irá resultar 3 porque o escopo do 'let' abrangiu apenas o bloco, diferente da atribuição na expressão if.
}
```

Comment: Provavelmente é por causa da versão do ECMAScript de destino.

Comment: Eu estava pensando em sair do babel para tsc em node, será que esse comportamento acontece com as ultimas versões do ECMAScript? Pois já virou um padrão o não uso de var em nodejs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque o `--target` (ou apenas `-t`) **por padrão** irá converter para ES3, bem semelhante ao ES5, mas tem muitas APIs que não existem nele (apesar que nesse caso depende do navegador) e não irá usar o `strict mode` que é algo do ES5, como é dito na documentação:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

O uso do ES3 como padrão provavelmente é para tentar ser o mais retrocompatível possível, claro que isso volta e meia pode implicar em algum efeito não desejado.

Se você acredita que vai usar o TypeScript só em ambiente que suportarão ES6+ então basta especificar para converter para o desejado, lembrando que `let` não é do ES5, portanto se deseja usar exatamente como é basta ajustar no compilador:

```
tsc meuscript.ts -t ES6
```

Os valores suportados por `--target` (`-t`) são:

- ES3 (padrão)
- ES5
- ES6 ou ES2015
- ES2016
- ES2017
- ES2018
- ES2019
- ES2020
- ESNext (esse são todas ultimas funcionalidades propostas em https://github.com/tc39/proposals, o que claro não há garantias de correr em todos ambientes, já que isso é para "converter")

Então esse é o motivo, o padrão por enquanto é o ES3, mas você tem controle total de ajustar para o que lhe convêm.

O TypeScript também tem muitos ambientes suportados e cada um trabalha de uma forma, então vou tentar resumir, o `tsconfig.json` é o arquivo de configuração na maioria dos projetos que usam TypeScript, com ele você poderá configurar nele como deseja que seja a conversão, exemplo incluindo algumas libs e conversão para ES2019:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",

  ...
 
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2019", "es2020.promise", "es2020.bigint", "es2020.string"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2019",

    ...
  }  
}
```

Documentação: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Answer (score 7):

Não posso responder de forma autoritativa em específico, mas pelo que conheço de compilação e [transpilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189894/101), faz algum sentido porque o controle extra que o `let` dá é o escopo, que o compilador do TypeScript já garantiu ser o adequado, então não tem porque mandar para o código JS algo para ele verificar de novo. Depois que ele sabe que está no escopo certo, quando o código JavaScript é gerado não tem mais motivo para o compilador JS cuidar disso. Seria um trabalho de compilação redundante. Eu imagino que compilar o `var` no JS seja mais rápido que compilar o `let`.

O código JS gerado pelo TS não precisa ser robusto, não precisa ser legível, não é para humanos, ele precisa ser eficiente e bem feito para tudo funcionar adequadamente, é outro nível de abstração.

De fato pode-se observar que ele protege a variável mudando o nome dela onde tem o `let`:

```
function foo() {
    var x = 1;
    var y = 3;
    if (true) {
        var x = 2;
        var y_1 = 4;
        console.log(x);
        console.log(y_1);
    }
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
}
```

Veja [funcionando e transpilado no **TypeScript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20foo()%7B%0D%0A%20%20var%20x%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20let%20y%20%3D%203%3B%0D%0A%20%20if%20(true)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20x%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20y%20%3D%204%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(x)%3B%20%2F%2FIr%C3%A1%20resultar%202.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(y)%3B%20%2F%2FIr%C3%A1%20resultar%204.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20console.log(x)%3B%20%2F%2FIr%C3%A1%20resultar%202%20porque%20o%20escopo%20do%20%27var%27%20abrangiu%20toda%20a%20fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20foo().%0D%0A%20%20console.log(y)%3B%20%2F%2FIr%C3%A1%20resultar%203%20porque%20o%20escopo%20do%20%27let%27%20abrangiu%20apenas%20o%20bloco%2C%20diferente%20da%20atribui%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20na%20express%C3%A3o%20if.%0D%0A%7D). [Também coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/Private.ts).

Além disso usando o `var` garante que roda em navegadores mais antigos que não possuem o `let`.

Comment: Faz todo sentido se o contexto já foi garantido

Comment: O problema que estou tendo, é que não consigo fazer minify com gulp com ES6.

Comment: @IvanFerrer você alterou a pergunta? Não pode, eu respondi o que foi perguntado. Se tem outra dúvida tem que fazer outra pergunta.

Comment: @Maniero, eu não alterei a pergunta, eu acrescentei informações, a sua resposta não responde a pergunta do porque o javascript sendo ECMAScript 6 faz as variáveis LET se transformar em VAR, isso não teria nem uma relação direta com typescript, eu dei apenas um exemplo, mas o javascript propriamente dito, reutilizar VAR, já que ela pode ser abandonada  pelo mesmo (como é dito por aí, já que está depreciado), não teria porque voltar a reutilizá-la em uma nova releitura depreciada.