# Métodos protegidos e privados da classe sendo acessados fora da classe utilizando Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Eu tenho uma classe com métodos **protegidos** e **privados**. Ao testar o meu código feito em **Typescript** (que é compilado para **ECMA**, ou melhor, **JS**), pude perceber que consigo acessar tais métodos fora da classe.

Isso me deixou pensativo, pois um dos pilares do encapsulamento é essa questão de você não conseguir acessar atributos e métodos protegidos e privados por fora da classe. Isso daria erro em várias linguagens orientada a objetos, como PHP, Java. Porém não deu erro no Typescript.

Sei que o Typescript é compilado para JS. Porém ainda tenho a dúvida: É permitido acessar esses tipos de métodos, fora da classe, no Typescript ? Ele só foi aceito por causa da compilação para Javascript (que aceita esse tipo de coisa) ?

Vou deixar meu código para vocês observarem:

```js
class Banco {

  private cofreQtd: number = 10000;

  private debitarCofre(quantidade: number): number | string {
    if (this.cofreQtd >= quantidade) {
      this.cofreQtd -= quantidade;
      return this.cofreQtd;
    } else {
      return 'O cofre não possui a quantiade requisitada';
    }
  }

  protected sacarDoCaixa(quantidade: number) {
    return this.debitarCofre(quantidade);
  }

  public sacarDoCaixaEletronico(quantidade: number) {
    return this.debitarCofre(quantidade);
  }

}

const nubank = new Banco();
console.log(nubank.debitarCofre(1000));
console.log(nubank.sacarDoCaixa(1500));
console.log(nubank.sacarDoCaixaEletronico(1500));
```

OBS: Eu consigo ter saída nos dois primeiros console.log, que exibem retorno de métodos privados e protegidos respectivamente.

Comment: Como respondi em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/487905/3635, o TypeScript passa pelo processo de transpilação para JavaScript, e a configuração padrão costuma ser ES3 no tsc, e o que não tem suporte no `--target` definido (ou padrão) provavelmente será contornado, como é o caso do `let` se tornar `var`. Você ainda pode usar o `#` como prefixo dos métodos ou propriedades: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

Comment: De uma lida [nessa documentação](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#caveats) onde diz que os modificadores de visibilidade `private` e `protected` são aplicados apenas durante a verificação de tipos e que construções em runtime do JavaScript como `in` ou pesquisa de propriedade simples ainda podem acessar membros `private` ou `protected`. Durante a durante a verificação de tipo propriedades `private` podem serem acessadas usando notação de colchetes.

Answer (score -4):

Você está correto ao perceber que o Typescript permite acessar métodos privados e protegidos fora da classe. Isso ocorre porque o Typescript é apenas uma linguagem que adiciona tipagem estática ao Javascript, mas após ser compilado, ainda é Javascript puro.

O Javascript não possui suporte nativo para modificadores de acesso como private e protected. Então mesmo declarando um método como privado no Typescript, após compilar para JS isso não terá nenhum efeito e você conseguirá acessar o método normalmente.

Portanto, isso é uma limitação do Javascript e não especificamente do Typescript. O Typescript não consegue impor regras de encapsulamento mais rígidas porque no final das contas o código é transformado em Javascript.

Então resumindo, mesmo declarando métodos privados e protegidos no Typescript, isso não terá efeito algum depois de compilado para JS. É permitido acessar esses métodos fora da classe em Typescript/Javascript. As declarações de private/protected servem mais para expressar intenção dentro do código Typescript, não para impor encapsulamento de fato.

Comment: A informação está equivocada, Javascript possui sim o [modificador de acesso privado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields).