# Como ver a implementação do código TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Em várias linguagens de programação que trabalhei ou atualmente atuo, eu consigo ver a implementação dos códigos desenvolvidos.

Em Dart ou Java por exemplo, consigo ir até o código fonte e analisar a implementação e, assim, consigo tomar a minha ação perante aquela um determinado método, isso vale para *libs* ou para o *core*.

Em TypeScript, eu tenho somente uma interface, e muitas vezes não consigo ver a implementação por debaixo dos panos. Se esse parada é código aberto, porque ele não exibe? Se for possível, como faz para exibir isto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TypeScript é uma linguagem que roda em cima de JavaScript. Pelo menos ela foi pensada para isto, nada impede um dia ela mudar de rumo, mas o objetivo é continuar assim. Ela usa uma técnica chamada [transpilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189894/101) onde o compilador lê o código em TS e escreve outro em JS. O código em TS não precisa ser distribuído em lugar algum. O código em JS é distribuído e é este que você pode ver. A não ser que quem escreveu o código TS lhe forneça diretamente.

Se está procurando os fontes da biblioteca de TS então não tem, pelo menos nada substancial, ela usa a biblioteca de JS. Se quer os fontes do compilador tem em https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript. Ali tem alguma coisa de biblioteca, basicamente para estabelecer contratos o que já existe em JS.

Se o que está falando sobre `interface` é justamente que essa biblioteca publicada aí só tem essas declarações e não a implementação do código dessas interfaces então não tem o que mostrar porque ela não implementada nada (ou quase nada), é o que eu disse já está tudo pronto na biblioteca do JS. O que você está vendo nesses arquivos `.d.ts` é só uma forma de criar os contratos para o que já existe e poder usar no seu código de acordo com as regras da linguagem. Como no JS não tem contrato, não tem interfaces e tipos, e TS tem, então a única coisa que TS tem que adicionar é o contrato a tudo, por isso cria as interfaces e diz quais são os tipos que uma função aceita.

Interfaces precisam ser implementadas para usar, mas elas já estão em JS, não tem porque fazer de novo, só traria problemas tentar fazê-lo novamente.

O objetivo de TypeScript é basicamente criar contratos para JavaScript e dar mais robustez e permitir bases de códigos maiores e mais complexas do que dá para fazer em JS.

A maioria das bibliotecas disponíveis para JS tem o mesmo recurso de criar os contratos para uso de forma estaticamente tipada (ainda que esse termo não fica bem neste tipo de linguagem, porque ela tem uma casca assim, mas no fim ele gerará algo que tem o mesmo problema de performance da tipagem dinâmica, e nada impede que em outro ponto a robustez seja burlada). O local que centraliza isto é o [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/). Ali tem os contratos, as implementações estão nas libs escritas em JS sem a parte do contrato que é um recurso que JS não tem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Se a biblioteca (lib) que você está usando, foi escrita em Typescript, você pode ler o código fonte dela da mesma forma que você faria com Java: acessando o repositório daquela biblioteca (se for open-source ou se você tiver acesso).

Porém o Typescript pode usar qualquer biblioteca escrita em Javascript ou que é compilada para Javascript, mesmo as que não foram escritas em Typescript. Nesses casos, são criadas interfaces para facilitar a sua utilização com o Typescript, seja pelo próprio criador da biblioteca ou por algum contribuidor do projeto [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). Por isso não há código-fonte em Typescript para ler, apenas o Javascript.