# Por que meu programa não exibe os valores de saída?

Tags: javascript

```
var anoAtual = 0
var anonasci = 0

const idade = function(cl){
    anoAtual - anonasci
    console.log(anoAtual - anonasci)
}

const imprimirresultado = function(c){

    if(idade >18){
        console.log(` sua idade é ${idade} você já pode dirigir`)

    }else if(idade < 18){
        console.log(`sua idade é ${idade} você ainda não pode dirigir`)
    }
}
anoAtual= 2020
anonasci= 2005

imprimirresultado()
```

Ao executar no console não obtenho retorno.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tem diversos problemas no código. Alguns não impedem ele de funcionar, mas não é assim que se faz códigos reais e pode estar aprendendo errado se continuar fazendo desta forma, então vou mostrar a forma mais correta.

Se vai usar funções, use-as da maneira como elas foram concebidas. Você passa dados para ela, então ela executa alguma coisa, e eventualmente resulta em algo que é retornado. Isso não existe no seu código, ele pega dados de fora delas e isso apesar de funcionar é errado, causará problema no futuro quando for executar códigos mais complexos

Então vamos colocar parâmetros e retornar um dado na função onde isso deve acontecer. Toda comunicação da função com o mundo externo a ela deve se dar dessa forma não pegue dados que não pertencem a ela, a não ser se for um objeto que ela pertence, aí pode pegar o `this`, mas não faça com dados globais (até existe exceção para isso, mas só depois que dominar como faz todo o resto lide com esses casos, embora sempre dê para fazer sem nada global, só não é ideal em todos os casos).

Fazendo a primeira função retornar algo então podemos chamá-la e mandar calcular a idade.

Notou que eu mudei os nomes das funções? Dê nomes significativos para tudo, para variáveis e principalmente para funções. De início pode parecer bobo, mais isso ajuda fazer o código de forma correta e entende o que ele deve fazer.

Aí, dentro da segunda função eu chamo a primeira que calcula a idade (de forma simplificada, obviamente que isso tem erro e vários casos, não valida nada, mas para um exercício de codificação isso não importante tanto, só ter claro que a intenção não é calcular a idade de forma correta.

Com o dado retornando por essa função eu comparo com a idade permitida para dirigir. Note que a comparação estava errada, pode não ser importante, mas acho que isso pode ser um erro de codificação e não de requisito apenas, por isso estou falando. Na sua comparação apenas pessoas com 19 anos podem dirigir, e eu duvido que esta era a intenção. Para aceitar que pessoas com 18 anos possam dirigir teria que usar o operador de maior **ou igual**. Também poderia comparar contra 17, o que aí o operador de maior dá certo porque aceita o 18.

Eu tirei o `else if` porque ele não tem sentido, só o `else` resolve porque ou a pessoa tem 18 anos ou mais, ou ela não tem isso, não tem porque comparar algo que já é sabido. Se a primeira condição falhar ela deve cair na segunda todas as vezes, fica mais simples e mais semântico.

Um dos erros que estava cometendo era tentar chamar a função como se ela fosse uma variável. Para chamar funções sempre deve fazê-lo com parênteses, e passando os argumentos que ela espera receber. Em outra linguagem daria um erro ali porque a variável nem existe. Algumas pessoas acham que aprender JavaScript é fácil, mas esconder um erro óbvio desses pra mim gera confusão e desensina, eu acho muito pior, pode ser mais fácil para quem não tem pensamento lógico, mas aí a pessoa não deveria programar.

Ou pode ser que queria criar a variável mesmo, mas aí esquecer de chamar a função e guardar seu valor na variável. È até difícil interpretar qual era a intenção, mas pouco importa porque ambos estariam errados nesse caso.

Eu usei uma função normal do que uma variável que recebe uma função. Esse caso não precisa da função anônima que é um recurso que tem custo e não serve para qualquer coisa. Não use algo sem necessidade. Quando precisar disso aí aprenda usar dessa forma e só para os casos onde é útil.

Eu coloquei `;` porque funciona sem, mas tem caso que dá problema, é raro, mas dá, e o dia que der com você poderá ficar sofrendo um tempão por causa disso. Acostume-se fazer o código de forma mais organizada possível, isso ajuda pensar melhor e entender bem o que está fazendo. Não cai o braço digitar uns caracteres a mais no código.

E por último juntei todo o código que era global. Até para não parecer que algumas variáveis precisam ser "declaradas" antes de usar dentro das funções. Isso vai construindo uma ideia errada do funcionamento das funções.

Usei o `let`, mas saiba que ele só funciona em navegadores relativamente modernos, só o use se vai usar um [utilitário que rebaixa o código para navegadores antigos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189894/101) ou se tem garantias que ele só rodará em *browser* moderno, o que é o caso de um exercício. Sim, desenvolver software é bem mais complicado que só escrever comando na linguagem.

```js
function calculaIdade(anoAtual, anoNascimento) {
    return anoAtual - anoNascimento;
}

function imprimeSePodeDirigir(anoAtual, anoNascimento) {
let idade = calculaIdade(anoAtual, anoNascimento);
    if (idade >= 18) {
        console.log(` sua idade é ${idade} você já pode dirigir`);
    } else {
        console.log(`sua idade é ${idade} você ainda não pode dirigir`);
    }
}
let anoAtual = 2020;
let anoNascimento = 2005;
imprimeSePodeDirigir(anoAtual, anoNascimento);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/AgeSimple.js).

Mudar um detalhe no seu código pode fazê-lo funcionar, mas ele ainda será considerado errado. Espero ter ajudado aprender a forma correta e possa evoluir no próximo código.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Answer (score 7):

Existem alguns pontos que estão impedindo que seu código exiba algo no console.

- Você utiliza a variável `idade` nas condições dentro da
  `imprimirresultado`, porém essa variável na verdade contém uma
  função.
- Ambas as funções declaradas recebem um parâmetro não utilizado.
- A função presente em `idade`, calcula a idade mas não retorna a mesma, apenas exibe no console.
- Suas condições de idade verificam maior que 18 e menor que 18, porém se a idade for exatamente 18,nada será feito.

---

Algumas possíveis correções:

A função presente em `idade`, passa a retornar o cálculo da idade, além disso, o parâmetro não utilizado é removido, também é possível remover esse `console.log`, mas isso você decide:

```
const idade = function() {
    let idadeAtual = anoAtual - anonasci;
    console.log(idadeAtual);
    return idadeAtual;
}
```

A função presente em `imprimirresultado`, passa a utilizar a executar a função `idade` e com o seu retorno, exibe as informações sobre 18 anos, sendo que a comparação de 18 anos, passa a verificar `>= 18`, o parâmetro também foi removido já que não estava sendo utilizado:

```
const imprimirresultado = function(){
    let idadeAtual = idade();

    if(idadeAtual >= 18){
        console.log(` sua idade é ${idadeAtual} você já pode dirigir`);
    }else if(idadeAtual < 18){
        console.log(`sua idade é ${idadeAtual} você ainda não pode dirigir`);
    }
}
```

Com isso seu código já passa a ser executado de forma correta e exibir os valores no console, abaixo o código completo:

```js
var anoAtual = 0;
var anonasci = 0;

const idade = function(){
    let idadeAtual = anoAtual - anonasci;
    console.log(idadeAtual);
    return idadeAtual;
}

const imprimirresultado = function(){
    let idadeAtual = idade();

    if(idadeAtual >= 18){
        console.log(` sua idade é ${idadeAtual} você já pode dirigir`);
    }else if(idadeAtual < 18){
        console.log(`sua idade é ${idadeAtual} você ainda não pode dirigir`);
    }
}

anoAtual= 2020;
anonasci= 2005;

imprimirresultado();
```

Comment: pq ele retorna o 15 antes de retorna o resultado?

Comment: Porque dentro da função que você atribuiu em idade, existe um console.log. Até citei ele na explicação, ele não tem necessidade, mas não removi, deixei ele aí para você decidir o que quer fazer com ele =)

Answer (score 4):

O problema do seu código é que a variável `idade` da função `imprimirresultado` não existe no contexto da função, para resolver eu adicionei um retorno na função que calcula a idade e coloquei o valor para uma variável `i` que é utilizada pra comparação, veja funcionando abaixo:

```js
var anoAtual = 2020
var anonasci = 2005

const idade = function(cl){
    return(anoAtual - anonasci);
    console.log(anoAtual - anonasci)
}

const imprimirresultado = function(c){
var i = idade();

    if(i>18){
        console.log(` sua idade é ${i} você já pode dirigir`)

    }else if(i< 18){
        console.log(`sua idade é ${i} você ainda não pode dirigir`)
    }
}
anoAtual= 2020
anonasci= 2005

imprimirresultado()
```

Comment: vlw cara, eu tava tentando declarar a variavel idade como this