# Como que se "traduz" uma linguagem de programação para outra?

Tags: compilação, paradigma-de-programação, tradução

Recentemente eu comecei meus estudos em desenvolvimento e me deparei com uma dúvida que muitas pessoas devem ter: como se transcreve (ou se traduz) as linhas de código entre linguagens de programação diferentes (C para Rust; Perl para Julia etc.)?

Cada linguagem tem a sua particularidade, o que torna fazer isso manualmente uma tarefa hercúlea. Eu até topei num [arquivo de uma aula da disciplina de paradigmas da PUC-RS](https://www.inf.pucrs.br/%7Egustavo/disciplinas/pli/material/paradigmas-aula08.pdf), que define como isso ocorre, dando dois exemplos de categorias de software para isso.

Fora isso, seria somente o passo-a-passo manual mesmo?

Comment: Talvez sua duvida seja respondida com transpiladores, correto?: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189894/o-que-%c3%a9-transpila%c3%a7%c3%a3o/189899#189899 .

Comment: Exceto em programas **muito** simples, ou em casos que foram pensados pra isso (como transpilar TypeScript para JavaScript, já que TS foi projetada para ser assim), geralmente não é viável traduzir linha a linha. Uma linguagem pode ter funções prontas pra algo, que outra não tem. Ou uma construção sintática que faz várias coisas em uma linha, que em outra não é possível. Ou instruções completamente incompatíveis. Ou... a lista é imensa, simplesmente não vale a pena. Mais "fácil" analisar o que o programa original faz e reescrever na outra linguagem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem simples, não traduz.

Claro que é possível fazer, mas não costuma compensar.

Existem casos que até criam ferramentas pra traduzir quando as linguagens sejam muito parecidas em semântica, o que é raro.

Sintaxe é fácil demais traduzir, é mais fácil que traduzir língua natural. O problema sempre é a semântica.

Então linguagens que tem mais a sintaxe como diferencial e algumas poucas diferenças semânticas da linguagem original que podem ser emuladas na outra que é o alvo da tradução, aí é possível fazer uma ferramenta que ajude.

Essa ferramenta é basicamente um [compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101). Mais especificamente um [transpilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189894/101).

Quando isso não é possível por uma razão ou outra, tem que fazer manual.

A vantagem do manual é que você pode traduzir virtualmente qualquer coisa, já que todas as linguagens de programação são [*turing complete*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101).

Mas o trabalho que isso vai dar pode ser monumental. Muito mesmo, absolutamente impraticável, porque pode ser que precise traduzir até a biblioteca padrão ou outras usadas na linguagem que serve de fonte. Não é só traduzir o seu código em muitos casos. Em outros, pode ser bem mais fácil, é só o trabalho enorme que já consegue perceber.

E claro, a ineficiência do código pode ser outro ponto a ser observado. Mesmo que rode e dê o mesmo resultado, não quer dizer que fará isso de forma rápida e econômica como era no código original.

Aí começa compensar fazer outro código na mão, eventualmente usando o original como referência, mas escrevendo um novo código e idiomático para a linguagem final. Em geral será melhor que fazer a tradução manual pura e simples.

Já imaginou a quantidade de *bugs* que pode gerar nessa tradução?

Se os paradigmas forem diferentes, ou filosofia geral, nem tente, a não ser como um exercício de masoquismo. Gaste seu tempo com coisas mais frutíferas.

Então nem tente converter de Python para Java e vice-versa. Pode tentar de C para Rust, já o contrário... Nem precisa de esforço entre JavaScript e TypeScript. Mas até isso pode ser complicado. Fazer TypeScript idiomático é bem complicado, mesmo JS sendo compatível com TS, e tecnicamente, já é código TS.

Me lembro que pegaram o compilador de C++ e converteram para D com ferramenta, pelo menos partes. Até hoje, mesmo muita gente mexendo para melhorar nele por anos para transformar em código idiomático manualmente, ainda é um código muito feito e ruim. Mas teve vantagens.

Obviamente que isso não vale para códigos muito simples. "Hello World" dá pra fazer sem dores de cabeça :)

Então, sim, ou é automático, ou é manual.